# Angular | Refresh table every 5 seconds with Timer

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using material table in a page and I want it the table datasource to be refreshed every 5 seconds so that any change in values will be reflected in the table. This is what I've done now:

```
everyFiveSeconds: Observable<number> = timer(0, 5000);

ngOnInit() {
this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(() => {
  this.getComponents();
});
```

`getComponents()` sends a get request and paginates the output to a material table. However the problem is, once I load this page initially, the get request gets made every 5 seconds. But the application keeps sending the request even if I navigate to another page. If I revisit the page, the request gets sent every 2.5 seconds and the frequency of requests keep increasing if I repeat it.

How can I modify my code so that this get request is sent only when I am sitting at this component page and also make sure if I revisit this page, multiple timers are not getting created?

Comment: If you subscribed you want to unsubscribe to it, you can unsubscribe the timer observable via when component destroy lifecycle event.

Comment: @penleychan : It seems to be working. But I'd like you to verify it. I added `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` inside a newly created ngonDestroy function. `this.subscription` is the return value of the subscribe() function inside ngOnInit. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's something like this:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

export class MyClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription;
    everyFiveSeconds: Observable<number> = timer(0, 5000);
    
     ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(() => {
         this.getComponents();
       });
     }
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out this exact solution based on the first reply I got but this helps as a verification. So I'll mark the question solved. Thanks!

Comment: import { timer } from 'rxjs'; related definiton must be imported.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended that you unsubscribe from all of your subscriptions to observables that have an indefinite number of emissions. Do not ever assume that the framework is gonna do it for you. You can do that using the unsubscribe, but personally I prefer to do it by using a `Subject` along with a `takeUntil` operator. This approach is particularly useful if you have several observables to unsubscribe from (although I like to keep a pattern throughout my code, so I use it even when I have a single subscription to take care of):

```js
private _destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.everyFiveSeconds
    // You can do this with all of your subscriptions
    // using a single _destroy$ variable
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.getComponents();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this._destroy$ && !this._destroy$.closed) {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can understand how this is a good practice. However in my application, except for this single case where timer is used, it's always simple post requests where I get a single response just once. Would staying subscribed cause any problems?

Comment: Absolutely not.